# Building separated columns for each category from columns that categories are mixed

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning, stringr

I have a survey dataframe that contains evaluations of three categories. I do want to see evaluations of each category in each column, but it's mixed like this,

```
ID  q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 q6
1   c2 e1 c1 e1 c3 e2
2   c1 e1 c3 e2 c2 e0
3   c3 e0 c2 e2 c1 e1
```

What I want to get is:

```
ID  c1 c2 c3
1   e1 e1 e2
2   e1 e0 e2
3   e1 e2 e0
```

However, trying several ways via stringr and dplyr, now I'm just stuck here:

```
ID  a1    a2    a3
1   c1-e1 c2-e1 c3-e2
2   c1-e1 c2-e0 c3-e2
3   c1-e1 c2-e2 c3-e0
```

Is there anyone who knows how to fix this problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the logic behind the initial data and your expected output? It's not clear to me what is going on here.

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks for the comment and my apology for the explanation! I'm trying to construct independent variables for regression analysis. In this case, evaluations of each categories(c1,c2,c3) would be three independent variables. Is it enough to give you the context?

Comment: @thelatemill so this survey asked respondents' evaluation for each category. But the order of question was randomized. They asked someone in the order of c2 > c1 > c3 (id 1 in the first matrix), and then they asked another as c1 > c3 > c2 (id 2). The survey team has not arranged this data by category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a stack to long, and then a reshape to wide format will accomplish this. There are about 3.2 million variations on this logic, but here's one:

```
tmp <- reshape(dat, idvar="ID", varying=list(c(2,4,6),c(3,5,7)),
               v.names=c("name","value"), direction="long", timevar=NULL)

#    ID name value
#1.1  1   c2    e1
#2.1  2   c1    e1
#3.1  3   c3    e0
#1.2  1   c1    e1
#2.2  2   c3    e2
#3.2  3   c2    e2
#1.3  1   c3    e2
#2.3  2   c2    e0
#3.3  3   c1    e1
```

This long format may even be usable for modelling purposes. If you definitely require the wide format, reshape again:

```
reshape(tmp, idvar="ID", timevar="name", direction="wide")

#    ID value.c2 value.c1 value.c3
#1.1  1       e1       e1       e2
#2.1  2       e0       e1       e2
#3.1  3       e2       e1       e0
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I just removed <idvar="ID"> because I already set that before. And wide format comment was really helpful too. My dependent variable is out of data frame I uploaded, so it's important to keep the row number and order. Now I will join this to a larger dataset. Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 2):

We could use `split` to separate values in column based on the column names.

If you have limited columns you could manually make columns (like I did) or do it programatically using `paste` and `seq` according to the structure of your columns.

```
cols <- c("q1", "q3", "q5")
vals <- c("q2", "q4", "q6")
do.call("cbind.data.frame", split(unlist(df[vals]), unlist(df[cols])))

#    c1 c2 c3
#q22 e1 e1 e0
#q41 e1 e2 e2
#q63 e1 e0 e2
```

You can `cbind` the first column to get `ID` column back.

```
cbind(df[1], do.call("cbind.data.frame", split(unlist(df[vals]), unlist(df[cols]))))

#    ID c1 c2 c3
#q22  1 e1 e1 e0
#q41  2 e1 e2 e2
#q63  3 e1 e0 e2
```

---

As mentioned by @Farah Nazifa if we want to maintain the row order as well for every column we can use `mapply` as follows.

```
col_values <- unlist(df[cols])
data.frame(mapply(function(x, y) x[y], 
    split(unlist(df[vals]), col_values), split(row(df[vals]), col_values)))

#    c1 c2 c3
#q41 e1 e1 e2
#q22 e1 e0 e2
#q63 e1 e2 e0
```

Comment: The answer is similar but not exact. Is there something more that could be done?

Comment: @FarahNazifa What is missing in the answer?

Comment: c2 & c3 doesn't match with the expected output

Comment: @FarahNazifa thanks, maybe you are right. I have updated the answer for that case as well.

Comment: Don't know why but "mapply" part didn't work for me. But I could learn how to handle this sort of situation. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `melt/dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(df1), measure = patterns('^q[135]', '^q[246]')),
           ID ~ value1, value.var = 'value2')
#    ID c1 c2 c3
#1:  1 e1 e1 e2
#2:  2 e1 e0 e2
#3:  3 e1 e2 e0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, q1 = c("c2", "c1", "c3"), q2 = c("e1", 
"e1", "e0"), q3 = c("c1", "c3", "c2"), q4 = c("e1", "e2", "e2"
 ), q5 = c("c3", "c2", "c1"), q6 = c("e2", "e0", "e1")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: It shows me the closest answer I wanted but can't keep the original row order. Could I ask you any further suggestion?

Comment: @Ji-WonLee  If I check your expected output, it is the same order.  Can you be more specific

Comment: @Ji-WonLee  I assume that your comment is based on some other dataset.  Is that true

Comment: (+) Nevermind! I figured this with other's comment. Thanks for your help tho.